# why am I getting a mass assignment error when my column is on my attr_accessible list

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment, attr-accessible

There are several related questions to this one. But none of the answers address my situation.

I am getting this error on my localhost when trying to create a new policy.

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: starts_on
```

In my policy.rb model though I have this:

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :policy_type

attr_accessible :starts_on,
                :ends_on,
                :i_agree_privacy_policy,
                :license,
                .
                .
                .etc...

validates:starts_on, :presence => true

def self.init(user, policy_type, load_user_profile = true)
    attributes = {
        :user => user,
        :policy_type => policy_type,
        :starts_on => Date.today
    }
    policy_type.policy_class.constantize.new(attributes)
end

etc...
end
```

The form is for insurance so its huge but its also not important here since I am creating the starts_on here with Date.today. Really stumped here and I've spent several hours on google the last couple of days to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I'm curious why you aren't using `Policy.new attributes` in the place of `policy_type.policy_class.constantize.new(attributes)`. What is policy_class returning?

Comment: I didn't write the line. But policy_class is a column in the policy_types table and it holds a string. I am trying to refactor the whole project actually and it included changing the policies table. but this column `starts_on` was in the old table. and I didn't touch the policy_types table

Comment: What type is field 'starts_on' of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting the "Can't mass assign" error on the actual class that `policy_type.policy_class` resolves to, not on `Policy`.

I would check whatever class `policy_type.policy_class` points to, and try adding `starts_on` to `attr_accessible` there.